# Benutzung des Partizip II zusammen mit "kommen" ("angerudert kommen")

Tags: tense, participle

Ich sah diesen Satz in einem Kinderbuch:

> Da kommt jemand mit einem kleinen Boot übers Wasser gerudert.

Auf Englisch wird das übersetzt als

> Someone comes rowing over in a boat.

Aber soviel ich weiss wird Partizip II (In diesem Fall *gerudert*) normalerweise entweder als Perfekt oder Adjektiv benutzt. Aber hier ist es weder das eine noch das andere.

Wenn ich die "-ing"- Endung (rowing) im Englischen sehe, behandle ich das im Kopf als Präsens oder Partizip I.
Aber als Partizip II habe ich das noch nie gesehen.

Könnte mir jemand diesen Grammatikaufbau erklären?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The German 'Kommen + Past Participle' Construction](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13572/the-german-kommen-past-participle-construction)

Comment: Duplikat auf englisch: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13572/the-german-kommen-past-participle-construction

Comment: Noch schöner wird es, wenn noch ein Verb der Wahrnehmung dazukommt: "Er sah in herangerudert kommen".

Comment: @tofro   Ist aber "Er sah ihn herangerudert kommen" nicht falsch konstruiert? Jedenfalls solange man sagen will, dass er selber rudert? Müsste es nicht "Er sah ihn heranrudern kommen" heißen? Während "Er sah ihn herangerudert kommen" hieße, dass er im Boot sitzt und jemand anderes rudert?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Der *Ersatzinfinitiv* ist meiner Meinung nach hier optional, weil das sowieso kein "richtiges Perfekt" ist. Aber möglicherweise täuscht mich hier mein Dialekt. Den Bedeutungsunterschied, den du da hineininterpretierst, sehe ich allerdings nicht.

Comment: @tofro   Ja, es war nur so ein momentanes Gefühl, bestärkt durch die kontrastive Wirkung des Alternativsatzes. Für sich genommen halt ich *Er sah ihn dahergerudert kommen* auch für eine umgangssprachlich wohlgeformte Konstruktion.

Answer (score 5):

Viel zu erklären gibt es da nicht. Es handelt sich um eine mögliche Verwendung des Verbs *kommen*, wobei dieses Verb mit einem zweiten Verb der Bewegung kombiniert wird.

Der [Duden-Eintrag zu *kommen*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kommen#Bedeutung1) führt unter Bedeutung 1 auf:

> in Verbindung mit einem Verb der Bewegung im 2. Partizip:
>   angeritten, angeradelt, angebraust kommen

Diese Konstruktion wird nicht sehr häufig verwendet und mir ist außer *kommen* auch kein anderes Verb präsent, das so verwendet werden kann.

Comment: +1, aber das ungewöhnliche ist hier bloß das Partizip II. Normalerweise würde man das Partizip I erwarten: *Er kommt rudern**d**.* Dieses ist aber schon mit einer anderen Bedeutung besetzt.

Comment: Ich würde nicht sagen, dass das Konstrukt "nicht sehr häufig verwendet wird", sondern das genaue Gegenteil.

Comment: Eine ähnliche Eigenheit hat das Verb "gehören" im Sinne von "Das Auto gehört mal repariert"

Comment: Es gibt mehrere Verben bzw. Verbverbände dieser Art, zu denen aber 'gehören + Partizip 2' nicht gehört, das ist nur eine der Möglichkeiten einer Passivkonstruktion (ihm gehört mal ordentlich der Kopf gewaschen). Mir fällt dazu grad nur 'bringen' ein: Unsere Katze bringt immer wieder tote Mäuse angeschleppt und legt sie uns auf die Fußmatte. Auch das bekommen-Passiv wirkt ähnlich. Es gibt eine ganze Reihe nicht grammatikalisierte Verbverbände, der sogenannte Absentiv hat seine grammatischen Weihen auch noch nicht sehr lange.

Comment: @RalfJoerres: "Unsere Katze bringt immer wieder tote Mäuse angeschleppt" klingt aber ziemlich nach Ruhrgebiet, oder einfach falsch. Hmmm... "Unsere Katze tut immer wieder tote Mäuse angeschleppt bringen" <g>

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: Ach so, und 'Wen/Was bringst du da jetzt wieder angeschleppt!?' ist dann auch falsch. Auf deine Definition von 'falsch' wäre ich gespannt.

Comment: Ja, das ist auch falsch oder wenigstens "Ruhrpott" oder ähnlich. Meine Definition von "falsch" ist "nicht richtig".

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: Das ist tautologisch bzw. inhaltsleer, soll vielleicht ein Scherz sein.

Comment: @Ralf: Mein Kommentar war kein Scherz. Nur der "Tu-Satz" war nicht ernst gemeint. Das andere schon: "angeschleppt bringen" ist m.E. schlicht falsch, ähnlich wie "anschleppen tun". Und meine Definition von "falsch" ist die übliche. Das Wort "anschleppen" beinhaltet schon das Bringen, also ist "angeschleppt bringen" Unsinn. Man kann einfach sagen: "Schau mal, was die Katze wieder anschleppt".

Comment: @Ralf: Man kann sagen: "... was die Katze wieder angeschleppt *hat*", aber nicht: "... angeschleppt *bringt*".

Comment: Einspruch gegen die Ruhrpott-These! Ich möchte hiermit anmerken, dass mir (hauptsächlich im Südwesten der BRD erstsprachsozialisiert) die Formulierung "Katze bringt Maus angeschleppt" nicht ruhrpöttlerisch vorkommt, eher allgemeindeutsch-umgangssprachlich. **"Was bringst du denn da wieder angeschleppt"** ist ein Satz, der für mich sowohl im Schriftdeutschen wie im Schwäbischen funktioniert. **"Was brengt der do au wieder aagschleppt?"** Womit ich - denke ich - ein gutes Argument gegen die Ruhrpottthese angeschleppt gebracht habe.

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann: Danke, seh' ich ähnlich.

Comment: @Christian: Naja, die Region war mir nicht klar (Ruhrpott war nur geraten), ist aber m.E. regional und eben nicht allgemeindeutsch-umgangssprachlich. Du bist ja von da, also für dich klingt das vielleicht normaler. Vielleicht ist Ralf aus der gleichen Gegend?

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: Ja, ich bin von Essen weck.

Comment: @Rudy  Ha, i däät mol saa, wenn dees em Ruhrgebieed gsecht werd, ond au bei de Schwooba (ond ibrigens im Bayrischa au), no werd's halt oigetlich braktisch iiberall so sei, gell?

Comment: Ik zou eigenlijk in Nederlands moeten antwoorden, maar dat gaat waarschijnlijk te ver. Also, Essen+Schwabenland+Bayern sind zusammen nur ein kleiner Teil von Deutschland. <g>

Comment: "Die Katze bringt/schleppt wieder eine tote Maus an." genügt mir auch. Umgangssprachlich mag sie sie aber auch angeschleppt bringen.

Comment: @Christian: Na, da bisse abber mit dein Schwäbisch noch ganz gut dabei, würdich ma saang. Wat wir hier haabm, is ja nich son richtigen Dialekt, nur sonn angetäuschten.

Answer (score 1):

Fast alle Verbverbindungen mit einem Partizip 2 sind grammatikalisiert:

> er *hat* den Test *bestanden* = *Perfekt*
>
> wir *hatten* die Schlüssel *verlegt* = *Plusquamperfekt*
>
> sie *wird* nach Hause *gefahren sein* = *Futur 2*, hier (wie meist) als
> Vermutung
>
> hier *wird gearbeitet* = *werden-Passiv*
>
> die Fenster *sind* frisch *lackiert* = *sein-Passiv (Zustandspassiv)*

Viele Partizipien sind lexikalisiert:

> sie war ziemlich *aufgeregt* = *Adjektiv*, hier prädikativ
>
> er nahm die Nachricht vom Tod seines Onkels *gefasst* auf = *Adverb* (oder *Depiktiv / freies Prädikativ*)

Manche dieser grammatisch einzuordnenden Fälle sind differenziert zu betrachten:

> er schreibt jeden Vormittag vier Stunden an seiner Doktorarbeit und *hat* dabei das Fenster *geöffnet* / das Telefon *abgestellt*

wäre hier kaum als Perfekt sinnvoll zu beschreiben.

Daneben gibt es eine vermutlich kleinere Anzahl von Verbindungen mit einem Partizip 2, bei denen nicht sofort klar ist, ob man sie als grammatikalisiert oder als lexikalisiert ansehen soll. Einige dieser Verbindungen werden inzwischen unter grammatischer Perspektive gesehen:

> er *bekam* (*kriegte / erhielt*) ein Fotoalbum *geschenkt* =
> *'bekommen'-Passiv*
>
> ihm *gehört* einmal die Meinung *gesagt* = *Passiv-Ersatz mit 'gehören'*

Interessant sind die hier besprochenen Verbindungen mit '*kommen*' + *Partizip 2*, die eine Fortbewegungsweise mit der Bewegungsrichtung 'zum Sprecher bzw. zum inneren Betrachtort hin' kombinieren:

> Die Konferenzteilnehmer *kamen* alle in großen Limousinen mit Chauffeur
> *vorgefahren*.

Diese Konstruktionen mit '*kommen*' bilden eine Serie; '*kommen*' hat hier eine hilfsverb-ähnliche Funktion und trägt u.a. die Tempusmarkierung: '*Sie **kommt** / **kam** angelaufen / sie **ist** da auf einmal angerast **gekommen**... / wart's nur ab, die **wird** mit Sicherheit noch einmal angeschoben **kommen** und danach fragen.*' Hier können auch andere Präfixverben als solche mit *an-* im Partizip 2 stehen: '*Es kamen viele **her**gelaufen, um zu erfahren, was passiert war. / "Heinrich, der von ungefähr in der Nähe spaziren ging, kam **herbei**gelaufen, und fragte, was es gebe?"* (J. H. Campe (Hg.): Geschichte Sandford's und Merton's: für Kinder erzählt, Band 1) und andere.

Es gibt weitere derartige Verbindungen, die einerseits nicht unter die oben genannten grammatischen Kategorien fallen und die andererseits, wenn überhaupt, dann nur sehr kleine Serien bilden. Ich zähle ein paar beispielhaft auf.

- *etw irgendwo versteckt / verborgen halten*: Der Mann hielt ein Messer unter der Jacke versteckt.
- *jn gefangen halten*: Die Täter hielten ihre Geisel zwei Jahre lang gefangen.
- *sich bedeckt halten*: Von Journalisten befragt hielt sich der Innenminister bedeckt.
- *sich geschlossen halten*: Halt dich geschlossen! (= halt den Mund)
- *etw geöffnet halten*: Wir halten unsere Verkaufsstelle die ganze Nacht geöffnet.
- *etw/jn getrennt halten*: Bei vielen Fußballspielen muss die Polizei die Fans der gegnerischen Mannschaften getrennt halten.
- *jm überlassen bleiben*: Es bleibt Ihnen überlassen, wie Sie damit umgehen wollen.
- *jm vorbehalten bleiben*: Es bleibt dir vorbehalten, ob du da mitmachen willst.
- *jm unbenommen / freigestellt / anheimgestellt bleiben*: Es bleibt Ihnen unbenommen / freigestellt, Anzeige zu erstatten.
- *irgendwo beschrieben stehen*: Das steht in der Bedienungsanleitung so beschrieben.
- *irgendwo geschrieben stehen* (auch biblisch): "Jesus aber antwortete und sprach: Es steht geschrieben (5.Mose 8,3): 'Der Mensch lebt nicht vom Brot allein...'"
- daraus figurativ: *jm im Gesicht geschrieben stehen*: Die Anspannung stand ihm deutlich im Gesicht geschrieben.
- anlog: *irgendwo schwarz auf weiß gedruckt stehen, irgendwo ausführlich erläutert / erörtert / dargelegt ... stehen*
- Redensart: *dastehen wie bestellt und nicht abgeholt*: Sie stand auf der Party herum wie bestellt und nicht abgeholt und hielt sich an ihrem Cocktailglas fest.
- *sich interessiert / engagiert / motiviert ... zeigen*: Er zeigte sich bei seiner Ausbildung sehr engagiert.
- *sich als (un)geeignet / unqualifiziert / überqualifiziert durchschnittlich begabt ... erweisen / herausstellen*: Der Neue erwies sich als leicht übermotiviert und ging allen auf die Nerven.
- *jn gefangen nehmen*: Er wurde an der Grenze gefangen genommen.
- *etw verloren glauben*: Er glaubte die Partie bereits verloren, als sein Gegenspieler einen entscheidenden Fehler machte.
- *verloren gehen*: Ihr sind in einem halben Jahr drei Monatstickets verloren gegangen.
- *etw/jn verloren geben*: Weitere Versuche erschienen ihr sinnlos, es blieb ihr nichts anderes übrig, als die Dateien auf der verschlüsselten Partition verloren zu geben.
- *geöffnet haben*: Der Laden hat erst ab acht geöffnet.

In manchen dieser Kombinationen kann das Partizip 2 als Adjektiv aufgefasst werden. Dies ist im Einzelfall schwer zu entscheiden.

Teilweise sind diese Verbindungen stilistisch markiert, z.B. umgangssprachlich (*der Laden hat noch nicht geöffnet*) oder archaisch (*es steht geschrieben*) oder hochsprachlich (*es bleibt den Beteiligten unbenommen*, die Unterschrift zu verweigern).